# When trying to create an MSI getting error has no digital signature, or has a digital signature that is not verified

Tags: windows, digital-signature, signature

When we are trying to generate an MSI using a tool supplied by HP ALM, we get the following error

This is happening only on one machine but works fine on other machine so we think something is wrong on this machine itself

***Questions***

1. Any way to bypass this digital signature validation requirement?
2. What could i missing on this machine which is causing this issue

***Error***

[5/18/2016 11:29:08 AM]: INFO: System.Exception: The file D:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP ALM Client MSI Generator 11.52\work\Install\QTGrid2.dll has no digital signature, or has a digital signature that is not verified ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The signature verification failed due to error: 2148098053
   at ClientMSIGenerator.WinTrust.VerifyEmbeddedSignature(String fileName)
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.VerifyFileSignature(String file)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.VerifyFileSignature(String file)
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.CreateDirectoriesAndDownloadFiles()
[5/18/2016 11:29:08 AM]: FATAL: Failed at download phase: see previous log messages for more details
[5/18/2016 11:29:08 AM]: INFO: System.Exception: The file D:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP ALM Client MSI Generator 11.52\work\Install\QTGrid2.dll has no digital signature, or has a digital signature that is not verified ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The signature verification failed due to error: 2148098053
   at ClientMSIGenerator.WinTrust.VerifyEmbeddedSignature(String fileName)
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.VerifyFileSignature(String file)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.CreateDirectoriesAndDownloadFiles()
   at ClientMSIGenerator.DownloadEngine.BuildDownloadList()
   at ClientMSIGenerator.Builder.ExecuteJob(BuildParameters bp, List`1 genSettingsList)

Comment: issue was it was missing Global Digital Certificate adding that fixed our issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to D:\Program Files (x86)\HP\HP ALM Client MSI Generator 11.52\work\Install\QTGrid2.dll

Right Click and Select Properties

See who the countersignatures are from

Click on the Countersignature : Name of signer > Details

[image: counter signature root cert invalid]

Then click View Certificate above and install the Root Certificate for that particular CA

[image: Global root ca]

Answer (score -1):

what is the OS? Windows 8, 10?
To turn OFF the Digital signature do these steps:-
1. Open the Command Prompt window by clicking the Start button, clicking All Programs, clicking Accessories, and then Right clicking Command Prompt and select 
    "Run as Administrator".
2. On the Command Prompt type in the command “Bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks ON” without the quotes.
This will disable the Digital Signature.

Comment: You should take some time to properly format your answer.  Does the solution change if they the author is using Windows 8 or Windows 10.  Why would the author disable signed drivers, QTGrid2.dll is causing the error, and that isn't even a device driver.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i will try this next time on another machine

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)